# Store procedure not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.1

Table Schame for raddacct & radacctold(Both have the same structure just the engine is different)

```
CREATE TABLE `radacctold` (
  `RadAcctId` bigint(21) NOT NULL,
  `AcctSessionId` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `AcctUniqueId` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `UserName` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `Realm` varchar(64) default '',
  `NASIPAddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `NASPortId` int(12) default NULL,
  `NASPortType` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `AcctStartTime` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `AcctStopTime` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `AcctSessionTime` int(12) default NULL,
  `AcctAuthentic` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `ConnectInfo_start` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `ConnectInfo_stop` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `AcctInputOctets` int(12) unsigned default NULL,
  `AcctOutputOctets` bigint(12) default NULL,
  `CalledStationId` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `CallingStationId` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `AcctTerminateCause` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `ServiceType` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `FramedProtocol` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `FramedIPAddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `AcctStartDelay` int(12) default NULL,
  `AcctStopDelay` int(12) default NULL
) ENGINE = ARCHIVE;


CREATE PROCEDURE radius.archive_acct()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO radacctold
    SELECT * FROM radacct
    WHERE acctstoptime > 0
    AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
  DELETE FROM radacct
    WHERE acctstoptime > 0
    AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
END

it return with error
CREATE PROCEDURE radius.archive_acct()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO radacctold
    SELECT * FROM radacct
    WHERE acctstoptime > 0
    AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);

/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 3 queries: 0.000 sec. */
```

Comment: -->  "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't change the [DELIMITER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

> Use of multiple statements requires that a client is able to send
>   statement strings containing the ; statement delimiter. In the mysql
>   command-line client, this is handled with the **delimiter** command.
>   Changing the ; end-of-statement delimiter (for example, to //) permit
>   ; to be used in a program body.

Within MySql client you should define your procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE archive_acct()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO radacctold
  SELECT * 
    FROM radacct
   WHERE acctstoptime > 0
     AND DATE(acctstarttime) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
  DELETE 
    FROM radacct
   WHERE acctstoptime > 0
     AND DATE(acctstarttime) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Other than that your procedure compiles without other syntax errors.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9e41/1)** demo

Comment: The syntax error is fixed but however when execute it return "ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: The most probable cause is that columns in `radacctold` and `radacct` differ. That's why you should avoid using `*` in SELECT clause in production code. What you have to do is to explicitly define columns both in `INSERT INTO radacctold (col1, col2, ...)` and `SELECT col1, col2, ...`. To be able further help you with this you should post your tables' schema in your question.

Comment: Tks for the fast responce, i have edit the post again. please excuse the stucture.

Comment: Somehow they are not the same in your db. If they would've everything would work just fine. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9e41/1) with your schema and it works as expected.